# Python Pandas, make date time rounding based on value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, function

I need to only select the cases for sensor type == air to be rounded to the nearest 5 seconds but do not how I should use a function to make this happen.

I do have the following lines:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame({'timestamp' : ['2020-04-14 00:00:23', '2020-04-14 00:00:37',
                                      '2020-04-14 00:01:01', '2020-04-14 00:01:05',
                                      '2020-04-14 00:01:19'],
                       'sensor type' : ['sound', 'air', 'sound', 'air', 'sound']})
In [3]: df["timestamp"] = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)
In [4]: df["rounded_timestamp"] = df.groupby("sensor type").transform(lambda d: d.dt.round("5s"))
```

Which results in

```
In [5]: df
Out[5]:
        timestamp sensor type   rounded_timestamp
0 2020-04-14 00:00:23       sound 2020-04-14 00:00:25
1 2020-04-14 00:00:37         air 2020-04-14 00:00:35
2 2020-04-14 00:01:01       sound 2020-04-14 00:01:00
3 2020-04-14 00:01:05         air 2020-04-14 00:01:05
4 2020-04-14 00:01:19       sound 2020-04-14 00:01:20
```

Hence, I do have the column with the rounded times. But ONLY for air sensors the time should be rounded, how could I get a column with the rounded timestamps for air sensors and the non-rounded timestamps for the sound sensors?

Comment: Why are you using `groupby`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of solving this is with the `apply()` function to the DataFrame (not a series). What this does is lets you operate on a per-row basis if you set `axis=1`. This way, you can specify operations that need to apply to one column but can still access any other column you need to for that row for applying those operations conditionally.

```
df["rounded_timestamp"] = df.apply(lambda row: row["timestamp"].round("5s") 
                                   if row["sensor type"] == "air" 
                                   else row["timestamp"],
                                   axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks for your support! However, I do get an error "AttributeError: 'Timestamp' object has no attribute 'dt'", despite the fact that type of attribute is set to date time.. do you know how this could be overcome?

Comment: Oh, apologies. I didn't catch that. Take out the ```.dt```. It's an accessory that will give you the values contained in the series for vectorized operations and the like. For this, ```row["timestamp"]``` directly gives you the timestamp, so there's no need for the accessor.

Answer (score 0):

Just use this (adding **1** more line to your existing code):

**Edit:**
*tested on pandas 1.0.3 and python 3.6.9 on colab*

```
df['rounded_timestamp'] = df['timestamp']
df.loc[df['sensor type']=='air',"rounded_timestamp"] = df.loc[df['sensor type']=='air','timestamp'].dt.round("5s")
```

**Output:**

[image]

Comment: thank you, however I got an error : "A value is trying to be set on a copy of a slice from a DataFrame.
Try using .loc[row_indexer,col_indexer] = value instead" and the script is not working... do you know how to overcome?

Comment: what's your pandas version btw? I tested this out on colab on `1.0.3` and python `3.6.9`

Comment: Also, are you creating this data frame by filtering another bigger data frame?